# Face Recoginition Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, face-recognition

I want to do Face recoginition (Not Face Detection) in my Android and iOS app. I have studied a lot on Web and found following possible solutions:

1.) openCV: I don't want to go into writing my own API using this. Also, I don't have prior experience in JNI for Android.

2.) [Betaface API](http://betaface.com/demo.html#) So far this is good.

3.) [Sky Biometrics](https://www.skybiometry.com/) is also Good.

Now, I am searching for the solution from 3-5 days and came to know that I can use above API (so far I have decided to purchase license for Sky Biometrics). And this API will provide me a list of Features for the faces it recognised.

But, Now I am confused That how to use these features and save in my local data base to recognise faces from the pictures.So My queries are following

1.) How to convert Face features to Actual working Face recognition API means What is the actual algo or solution I can use to merge diffrent face features of a same person to identify him correctly.

2.) Uploading images and then creating database for Face-features set is a very time taking process. Do any one knows any **Android/iOS Face Recoginition SDK to** do this so that I can do this accurately and timely with no or less time taking process.

3.) Both solution-2 and 3 can be used with Images. Is there any other solution is available which can do the same with less efforts but with more accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am using  [Rekognition](https://rekognition.com/demo/face) API. And this is good enough to serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

OpenBR may be also interesting for you: http://openbiometrics.org/